# pass value into 'create view'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In context, I'm linking to 'create new post' from 'thread details'  and I need the post create to 'know' that it is linked to whatever thread it has just comes from.

I'm sure I would pass in the Thread_ID to the post create in the controller but I'm unsure how to do this.

Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: Amy, please do not put tags in the title. of the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using an ActionLink on the HtmlHelper then you just can pass additional routevalues to the call and retrieve them in your Controller-Action. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492936.aspx)

it should look like

```
Html.ActionLink("create new post", "Create", new { ThreadId = Thread_ID })
```

Also look at the other overloads for more control over the Controller/Action, Styles, etc.